# How to swap two pointers in multi-threaded c++ 17 program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I have two pointers: pA and pB. They points to two big hash map objects.
when the hash map pointed by pB is updated completely, I want to swap pB and pA.

In C++ 17, how to swap them fast and thread safe? Atomic? I am new to c++ 17.

Comment: atomic is c++11, and all you want is [atomic exchange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_exchange)

Comment: @Mgetz thanks, could you give me an example for exchanging two pointers.

Comment: Just some words of warning: An atomic update of a _single_ pointer can easily be achieved by using `std::atomic<Map*>`. _Two_ pointers can be swapped atomically by using `std::atomic<user_defined_pod_struct_of_the_two_pointers>` (`std::pair<Map*, Map*>` does not work). **However**, depending on your exact use-case **you may need an additional synchronization mechanism**: Other threads may continue to use the old hash map (now pointed-to by `pB`) even after the atomic update of `pA` from the "writer thread". This can yield a race condition if you plan to subsequently update the hash map `*pB`.

Comment: I am reopening because this solution is wait-free, whereas [marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512112/want-an-efficient-way-to-swap-two-pointers-in-c) provides a lock-free solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Atomic wait-free exchange of 2 pointers can be implemented in the following manner:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>

template<class T>
class Pointers2 {
    uintptr_t const ab_;
    std::atomic<uintptr_t> a_;

public:
    Pointers2(T* a, T* b)
        : ab_(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a) ^ reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(b))
        , a_(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a))
    {}

    T* a() const { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(a_.load(std::memory_order_acquire)); }
    T* b() const { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(a_.load(std::memory_order_acquire) ^ ab_); }
    void exchange() { a_.fetch_xor(ab_, std::memory_order_release); }
};

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    Pointers2<int> p2(&a, &b);
    assert(p2.a() == &a);
    assert(p2.b() == &b);
    p2.exchange();
    assert(p2.a() == &b);
    assert(p2.b() == &a);
    p2.exchange();
    assert(p2.a() == &a);
    assert(p2.b() == &b);
}
```

Acquire/release memory ordering is required to make sure that writes to shared data `T` do not get reordered past `exchange`.

Comment: A few comments on the code will be better for new people. Thanks.

Comment: @DeanChen It is based on the idea of exchanging 2 integers using xor: `void exchange(uintptr_t& a, uintptr_t& b) { a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b; }`.

Comment: question @MaximEgorushkin - this works fine but wouldn't the data that we are pointing to still need some locking?

Answer (score 1):

On x86-64 you can atomically exchange 2 pointers only if they are adjacent in memory and aligned to 16 bytes with `cmpxchg16b` instruction directly or by using `libatomic_ops`:

```
AO_INLINE int
AO_compare_double_and_swap_double_full(volatile AO_double_t *addr,
                                       AO_t old_val1, AO_t old_val2,
                                       AO_t new_val1, AO_t new_val2)
{
  char result;
  __asm__ __volatile__("lock; cmpxchg16b %0; setz %1"
                      : "=m"(*addr), "=a"(result)
                      : "m"(*addr), "d" (old_val2), "a" (old_val1),
                        "c" (new_val2), "b" (new_val1)
                      : "memory");
  return (int) result;
}
```

If `cmpxchg16b` is unavailable you need to use a mutex to make exchanging 2 pointers atomic.

Comment: The standard has [appropriate methods](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_exchange) of doing pointer exchanges without resorting to third party libraries or non-portable assembly.

Comment: @Mgetz You do not understand how https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_exchange works, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not just swap that should be atomic, but transaction should include check that swap should be made (is_the_hash_map_pointed_by_pB_updated_completely()).
Probably hash maps should be protected from concurrent usage with mutex.