# swap c++ map objects in multithreaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, multimap

I am new to c++ coding and have a need to swap/replace the old multimap object with the newly built multimap object, as this object will be cache I would like to replace the existing object only after building the new object and just replace the object itself. This will be used in a multithreaded environment, so using the atomic load. As described in this thread [Want an efficient way to swap two pointers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512112/want-an-efficient-way-to-swap-two-pointers-in-c][1]). I wrote this code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<atomic>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

// MultiMap Object
struct mmap{
multimap<string,int> stringTointmap;
};

// Structure to swap two instances of multimap
struct swapMap{
  mmap* m1;
  mmap* m2;
};

int main(){

//create Two Objects
mmap* old = new mmap();
mmap* new2= new mmap();

// populate first object
old->stringTointmap.insert(make_pair("old",1));
//populate second object
new2->stringTointmap.insert(make_pair("new1",2));

//swap two objects
atomic<swapMap> swap;
auto refresh=swap.load();
refresh= {swap.m2,swap.m1};
}
```

But I'm getting this error

```
error: expected expression
refresh= {swap.m2,swap.m1};
```

definitely, I'm missing something, could someone please help?

Comment: If you're new and are working on a new project, you should consider using at least C++11 and `shared_ptr<>()`... That way you're much more likely to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Why do you need to swap two objects? Don't you just need the new object to replace the old object? You don't need the old object to replace the new object, do you? (It sounds like an atomic shared_ptr would be perfect for this job.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes you're correct, I want to replace the old object with the new one in a thread-safe manner

Comment: @Raj Then just use an [atomic std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2). :)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I did this, atomic<shared_ptr<mmap*> > old = new mmap();
mmap* new2= new mmap();
old->stringTointmap.insert(make_pair("old",1));
new2->stringTointmap.insert(make_pair("new1",2));
old.exchange(new2); now getting " _Atomic cannot be applied to type 'std::__1::shared_ptr<mmap *>' which is not trivially copyable"

Comment: Doing `shared_ptr<mmap*>` pretty much defeats the point of the shared_ptr. Use `shared_ptr<mmap>`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Tried it no luck I still get the same error.

Comment: See my sample code below.

Comment: `mmap` is the name of a *nix function. You probably don't want to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's example code showing how to use atomic operations on a `std::shared_ptr` to do it.

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

std::shared_ptr<std::string> the_string;

int main()
{
    std::atomic_store(&the_string, std::make_shared<std::string>("first string"));

    std::thread thread(
        [&](){
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                {
                    // pin the current instance in memory so we can access it
                    std::shared_ptr<std::string> s = std::atomic_load(&the_string);

                    // access it
                    std::cout << *s << std::endl;
                }
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            }
        });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    // replace the current instance with a new instance allowing the old instance
    // to be removed when all threads are done with it
    std::atomic_store (&the_string, std::make_shared<std::string>("second string"));

    thread.join();
}
```

Output:

> first string
>   first string
>   second string
>   second string
>   second string

Comment: Thaks for the response, I tried this with the multimap object like this shared_ptr<multimap<string,int> >  stringTointmap; multimap<string,int> m1;
m1.insert(make_pair("1",1));
atomic_store(&stringTointmap,make_shared<multimap<string,int> >(m1));
this gives me an error no matching function for call to 'atomic_store',  I think I'm not passing the actual object in a right way to atomic_store

Comment: I tried your code as is, I still get the same error  no matching function for call to 'atomic_store'  candidate template ignored: could not match 'atomic' against 'shared_ptr'

Comment: I have this in my classpath /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/