# atomic operations on shared pointers, c++ versions

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, stdatomic

I was working on this thread [swap c++ map objects in multithreaded environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086143/swap-c-map-objects-in-multithreaded-environment/56086513#56086513)

However,

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

shared_ptr<std::string> the_string;

int main()
{
     atomic_store(&the_string, std::make_shared<std::string>("first string"));
}
```

gives a compile time error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'atomic_store'
     atomic_store(&the_string, std::make_shared<std::string>("first string"));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/atomic:1165:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'atomic' against 'shared_ptr'
atomic_store(volatile atomic<_Tp>* __o, _Tp __d) _NOEXCEPT
```

I did see a few threads on this problem and understand that it could be related to C++ version I have `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/` and `/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/` on another box, both give the same issue. Should I upgrade the C++ version?

I resolved this issue by passing -std=c++11 flag.

Comment: Which GCC version are you using on _this_ box?

Comment: gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC) on Linux and gcc -dumpversion 4.2.1 on mac . Trying to upgrade, any idea how to do it?

Comment: Also what compiler flags? Sometimes simply telling compiler tobuse new version is enough

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I didn't use any flags. g++ Test.cpp

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I was able to resolve this issue by passing the flag              -std=c++11

Comment: @Raj SO supports self-answers.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by passing the flag -std=c++11

Comment: I'd usually recommend `-std=gnu++11` unless you specifically want to disable some GNU extensions.  e.g. you have to use `__asm__` instead of `asm` with `-std=c++11`.  I can't think of any more-relevant keywords or extensions that are disabled, though, so it's normally fine.

Answer (score 0):

It compiles fine here with GCC 8.3 and Clang 8.0, so yes, you should upgrade your compiler.